# in-vendor bundle controller autoload for use annotation

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony4

I have a problem with my project, I can't load my controller in my CoreBundle, but I manage it with Composer for updating easily in production server.

All code is on my github : https://github.com/super-vizor.

Supervizor (the main app) call CoreBundle by composer, but after update, during cache clear process, it gives an error:

> "The file "../Controller" does not exist (in:
>   D:\Supervizor\supervizor\vendor\super-vizor\corebundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config)."

Why am I getting this error? How can I load my controller ?

Thanks for the response in advance and sorry for my English I'm French.

Comment: Using autowire in a bundle is a bit unusual.  This is just a guess but you might need to adjust your resource paths to '../../*' because the services file is down one directory.  Again, just a guess.

Comment: is for use bundle for plugin-like system, i try fix in journey :)

Comment: i can load my routes in Ressources/config in the defined bundle ?